# Finding the gcd for 2 polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5[y]$

Tags: polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

The question that I am having troubles to solve is as follows:

Find the gcd for these two polynomials in $\mathbb Z_5[y]$:
$$p(y) = y^4 + y^3 + 3y$$
$$q(y) = y^3 + y^2 - 2$$
Sorry for my poor presentation for the polynomials symbols.

Please give me some help, as I don't even know how to start. Thank you!

Comment: $p(y) = yq(y)$ because $-2=3$ in $ \mathbb{Z}_5$. So their gcd is $q(y)$

Comment: ^^^ which you'd discover in one step of the euclidean algorithm since $\,p \bmod q = p - y\:\!q = 5y\equiv 0.\,$ If you don't know how to start then you should review the Euclidean algorithm, since this is the most simple application of such.

Comment: Thank you, nrynn and Bill Dubuque, never thought it was that easy!